# Python no puede encontrar el módulo que acabo de instalar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Intenté crear mi primero chatbot por mi propio con la ayuda de Rasa y [este tutorial](https://chatbotslife.com/rasa-nlu-on-aws-28d962acbf53).

Sin embargo, descargé un modulo con pip3 y es como si nunca hubiera sido descargado :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/rasa_nlu$ sudo pip3 install simplejson
The directory '/home/mike/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/mike/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting simplejson
Installing collected packages: simplejson
Successfully installed simplejson-3.14.0
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/rasa_nlu$ python3 -m rasa_nlu.train -c config_spacy.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/mike/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/rasa_nlu/rasa_nlu/train.py", line 14, in <module>
    from rasa_nlu import utils, config
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/rasa_nlu/rasa_nlu/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import simplejson
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simplejson'
```

Sé que tuve problema con `pip3`

No es raro que ya no funcione en mi dispositivo y necesito reinstalarlo como lo muestre en este otra error :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/rasa_nlu$ sudo pip3 install simplejson
[sudo] password for mike: 
sudo: pip3: command not found

mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/rasa_nlu$ sudo pip3-2 install simplejson
sudo: pip3-2: command not found

mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/rasa_nlu$ sudo pip install simplejson
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named _internal

mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/rasa_nlu$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/mike/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/rasa_nlu$ sudo apt-get remove python3-pip; sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython3-dev libpython3.5-dev linux-headers-4.13.0-37 linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic
  python3-dev python3-wheel python3.5-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python3-pip
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 211 not upgraded.
After this operation, 569 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 330267 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python3-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-37 linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-pip
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 211 not upgraded.
Need to get 109 kB of archives.
After this operation, 569 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 python3-pip all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 [109 kB]
Fetched 109 kB in 0s (1 105 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package python3-pip.
(Reading database ... 330194 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-pip_8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up python3-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
```

Comment: Marine no debes nunca en principio instalar con sudo usando pip. Ten siempre mucho cuidado en que `pip` llamas y por tanto en que instalación de Python o entorno va a instalar el módulo de turno. Prueba `$ /home/mike/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install simplejson`

Comment: @FJSevilla Gracias FJ, fue un montón de tiempo que lo hice tan pronto como me encontré con un problema, pero prometí que no lo haría más. Oye, quién sabe que tal vez algún día seré lo suficientemente bueno para crear virtualenv sistemáticamente

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ModuleNotFoundError No puedo importar un módulo instalado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404776/modulenotfounderror-no-puedo-importar-un-m%c3%b3dulo-instalado)