# ModuleNotFoundError No puedo importar un módulo instalado

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, librería, modulos

En Python obtengo el error "Unable to import 'nose'" cuando lo quiero importar en un módulo que tengo instalado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto `pip list`, aparece en la lista dicha librería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta intenté instalar nuevamente la librería dentro de la carpeta en la que estoy trabajando, pero me dice que **los requerimientos ya están satisfechos.**

Buscando este mismo error, encontré que era posible arreglar este error modificando el nombre de los archivos, sin embargo no me sirvió en mí caso.

Tengo instalada la versión 3.8.2 de Python, no sé si eso influencia.

Esta es la **traza de error completa**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File
"c:/Users/juamp/Desktop/reverse_words/reverse_words_test.py", line 1, in
<module> from nose.tools import istest, eq_ ModuleNotFoundError: No module
named 'nose'
```

Comment: ¿Pero has corrido el código? eso es un "hint", es decir una pista de `pylint` pero tiene porque ser la realidad cuando lances el código, dependerá de la configuración y el entorno en el que esté `pylint`. De todas maneras corre el código y si te da error, pon la traza de error completa.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/juamp/Desktop/reverse_words/reverse_words_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nose.tools import istest, eq_
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nose'

@RubialesAlberto eso es lo que aparece cuando ejecuto el programa

Comment: Okay, ¿has verificado que estás en el que instalaste el paquete? Puedes ejecutar en el código `help('modules')` y verificar si en la lista que te da de vuelta aparece `nose`por favor :)

Comment: Si, aparece 'nose' cuando ejecuto dicho comando, es muy extraño

https://gyazo.com/49961aac8ccd55223f13b25ac523001f

Comment: Lo que hice fue ejecutar, desde la consola, el comando que me adjustaste previamente. Estos fueron los pasos que tomé:

- Moverme al directorio C:\Users\juamp\Desktop\reverse_words (donde está el código)
- Escribir 'python', que abre el intérprete de python si no me equivoco
-Colocar el comando que me indicaste, verificando que ahí aparece el módulo 'nose'

Comment: Vale, perfecto! Creo que casí lo tenemos, puedes por favor, ejecutar dicho comando, exactamente igual que cuando ejecutas `from nose.tools import istest, eq_` por favor.

Comment: Ahora sí. Cuando ejecuto de esa forma el comando, no aparece 'nose' entre los módulos disponibles. Se ve que lo había hecho mal antes, mis disculpas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115944/discussion-between-rubiales-alberto-and-juan-pablo-frers-campos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando distintos interpretes de Python a la hora de lanzar el fichero y en tu terminal. Por tanto cuando ejecutas `pip install ...` estás instalando los paquetes en otro interprete de Python del que usas para ejecutar el fichero.

**Las soluciones son**:

- Solución 1: Averiguar con el **gestor de entornos** que estás trabajando, puede ser `Anaconda`, `pyenv`, etc. y en ese caso activar el entorno de la manera correspondiente e instalar `nose`.
- Solución 2: instalar el módulo `nose` en el entorno de Python con el que estás ejecutando el fichero, para esto debes cambiar el `PYTHONPATH`.
- Solución 3: agregar el entorno de Python a donde tiene el módulo instalado en el fichero.

La primera solución no tiene más desarrollo, es activar el entorno e instalar con `pip` por ejemplo si nos encontramos en `Anaconda` ejecutamos el siguiente comando en la terminal:

```
activate nombre_entorno
```

**En linux** sería `conda activate ruta/al/entorno`

Si por el contrario **no tienes gestores de entorno**, y tienes distintas versiones de Python, prueba las siguientes soluciones.

## Solución 2

**Primero**: Averiguar cual es el directorio de Python cuando ejecutas

```
import os
import sys
print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
```

Esto nos devolvera donde se encuentra nuestro directorio de Python que usamos al ejecutar.

**Segundo**

Añadir este directorio al `PYTHONPATH` de Windows, lo puedes hacer con `set` poniendo `;` al final y agregando la runta anterior:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\url_de_python
```

**Con Linux** sería el comando `export`

Una vez hecho esto, ejecuta de nuevo el archivo de Python y todo debería funcionar.

## Solución 3

Cambiar dentro del fichero al directorio de Python donde está instalado, para ello ejecuta en la terminal (donde haces `pip install`)

```
where python
```

**En linux** sería `which python`

una vez tienes la ruta, dentro de tu archivo donde importas `nose` pon al principio del todo lo siguiente:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("agregamos_aqui/la_ruta/vista_con/wherepython")
```

y agregamos la ruta que nos mostro `where python`

**Advertencia:** Esto es un parche, ya que probablemente tengas que hacerlo en todos tus archivos de Python que vayas creando, por lo que tendrás que aprender a usar el gestor de entorno que tengas o cambiar el `PYTHONPATH`.

## Bonus

Como consejo siempre es recomendable entender y saber usar los entornos de Python y las variables del Path del sistema Operativo. No es una tarea que lleve mucho tiempo y resuelve muchos problemas.

Comment: Voy a quedar una **respuesta canónica**, para cualquiera que le suceda esto con cualquier paquete, ya que es bastante frecuente en el sitio. Con las distintas soluciones para abordar el problema.